# How to implement flatMap method of Future[Either[L, R]]

Tags: scala

Our app uses a lot of `Future[Either[Error, R]]` to return either a result or an error object. I would like to create a new class that merges the two so it can be use in for-comprehensions, i.e. if a function is successful (returns a Right), the next function is called, else return Error.

I've done the `map` method, but has trouble with `flatMap`.

```
class FutureEither[L, R](val future: Future[Either[L, R]]) {
  def map[S](f: R => S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): FutureEither[L, S] = {
    val result = future.map {
      case Right(r)    => Right(f(r))
      case Left(error) => Left(error)
    }
    new FutureEither(result)
  }

  def flatMap[S](f: R => FutureEither[L, S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): FutureEither[L, S] = ???
}
```

Would be great if someone can help me implement it, or general improvement suggestions thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this: `def flatten[T](f:Future[Either[Throwable, T]]):Future[T] = f.map{case Left(e) => throw e; case Right(t) => t}` ?

Comment: It is exactly a monad transformer: http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/stacking-future-and-either.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same, just do `future.flatMap` instead of `future.map`. And wrap the left case in a future:

```
def flatMap[S](f: R => FutureEither[L, S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): FutureEither[L, S] = {
  new FutureEither(future.flatMap{
    case Right(r) => f(r).future
    case Left(error) => Future(Left(error))
  })
}
```